# What's the deal with Chas?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, constantine-2014

I've very briefly done research on the character of Chas in the Hellblazer books, nothing in depth really, but I haven't found anything that references his seeming immortality.  His survival skills are possibly supernatural but this doesn't equate to him being able to survive deadly attacks.

> Being electrocuted in episode one and stabbed to death in episode 6 and healing afterwards

So is he immortal, or is he just very hard to kill?

Comment: If you go by the film ending, it turns out that he's (possibly) an angel in disguise; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gm-onsYCxuY

Comment: I'm asking about the show's version of Chas though.  Is it safe to assume that the creators of the show did the same with this incarnation?

Comment: In the comic he's basically human-normal. In the film, he's (possibly) supernatural but essentially human-normal until the last few seconds of the movie. In the TV series, he's possibly supernatural. He survives mortal wounds on at least two occasions with no visible injuries afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's not been revealed yet. You'll have to wait until episode 10 (assuming the show [lasts that long](https://tvline.com/2014/11/24/constantine-season-2-renewed-cancelled/))

The show's producer has explictly confirmed that Chas is not an immortal and that the reason for his resilience will be revealed farther into the series:

[image]

In a [recent interview](http://tvline.com/2014/11/14/constantine-season-1-spoilers-newcastle-gang-chas-not-immortal/), the show's backers have confirmed that his apparent immortality is something that will be revealed later:

> Remember how Chas died — then came back to life — in the series’
>   premiere? *“For some reason, people started translating that to the
>   idea that he’s immortal,”* Cerone said. ***“We promise you: He is not
>   immortal. There’s a very good reason that he’s coming back to life,
>   and the only spoiler I will give you is that these lives are not
>   infinite.”*** The EP added that an upcoming, flashback-filled episode
>   will introduce Chas’ estranged wife and daughter.

And Charles Halford, the actor who portrays him in the show has a very [similar story to tell](http://www.enstarz.com/articles/44430/20140821/constantine-series-premiere-charles-halford-talks-playing-a-very-human-character-with-some-survival-skills-video.htm):

> Chas does have some unusual origins and while Halford refused to
>   reveal whether or not his character is immortal on the show, he did
>   admit that Chas does get through a lot right off the bat.
>
> *"He does survive something in the pilot that anyone would probably die afterwards, so he does have some survival skills,"* claimed
>   Halford, ***"But the root of those survival skills is yet to be
>   determined in the coming episodes."***

Comment: Ok, so they're going to be going with the survival skills approach, but add on to his already 'possible' supernatural skills.  Thanks for this.

Comment: @Robert - Don't hold out too much hope. The show is on the verge of cancellation.

Comment: I've heard.  If only they had kept it faithful to the comics it wouldn't be on the verge.  Instead, they decided to make it the 'look at the attractive, yet talentless, actress we cast as Zed' show with her side kick Constantine.  Such a shame.

Comment: They've got 13 episodes contracted. It's possible that they may not air them all, but they're being produced.

Comment: @Richard Answer need an update